# What is the fastest way to convert v8::String to jstring in JNI?

Tags: java, android, performance, java-native-interface, v8

I would like to avoid string transformation during conversion. Because it is slow. I suggest that internally V8 `String` and Java `jstring` are the same sequence of wide char, so maybe it's possible to copy without de/encoding, or maybe even avoid copying completely?

```
v8::String::Value v8_text(args[1]); // get the v8 string from arguments
wchar_t* w_chars = (wchar_t*)(*v8_text);
jstring j_text = (Env)->NewString((jchar*)w_chars, v8_text.length());
```

is the above already the most efficient way?

than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, given some assumptions.

A Java string is a counted sequence of code units of the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode characters. The endianness is meant to match the default for the OS.

A JavaScript string is a counted sequence of [16-bit unsigned integers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.17).

V8 does not transform the data for strings unless you invoke the functions that do so (i.e., to ASCII or UTF-8).

So, if your input is in fact a Unicode character string with a UTF-16 encoding with the expected endianness then the code you give will work and should be the most efficient.

However,

```
wchar_t* w_chars = (wchar_t*)(*v8_text);
```

is a bit misleading since `wchar_t` has an implementation-dependent size. Ultimately, you just want to cast the pointer to `jchar *` so, if this step is necessary, I suggest `char16_t *` or `uint16_t *` instead since they express the assumption that the data is structured in 2 byte chunks with an endianness.